# Auto refresh logstash agent when input file changes

Tags: windows, powershell, logstash

I have logstash setup such that it takes input from a text file X. I used to manually copy newer results into the text file and logstash would auto update the results.

Now I am piping the results from another text file Y into X using windows power shell

```
 Get-Content Y -Wait | Out-File X -encoding utf8
```

The input file gets appended with the latest results, however logstash does not update those results in it's database. How I can get the auto update to work again?

Comment: Check the sincedb file for the offset into the file.

Comment: Depending on which version of Logstash you are using there are several issues with the file input on Windows. (see https://github.com/elastic/logstash/issues/2135 or https://github.com/logstash-plugins/logstash-input-file/issues/2)